# Unable resolve the Error in Spark "import static spark.Spark.*"

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am running Hello World spark example in java.

I have added **spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.jar** along with complete jars of the spark.

but the error is not resoved!. 
How can find the spark.Spark library.

After doing lot of search only I am requesting in StackOverFlow.

below is my code

```
package test;
import static spark.Spark.*;// Unable resolve this error in my eclipse

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the jar, but is it on the build of the project ?

Comment: try to replace import with org.apache.spark.*

Comment: I have added to build path , but my problem still not resolved!

Comment: when I inport "org.apache.spark.*" I am getting the exception at-->

Comment: get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World"); line on req

Comment: @rajkumarchilukuri You use dependency of Apache Spark, while writing code from SparkJava library. Please see my answer, you must change your dependency

Comment: Thanks Its Worked!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use [SparkJava](http://sparkjava.com/) library, please  go to [download](http://sparkjava.com/download.html) page and use Maven dependency or JAR from ZIP package

If you want to use [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org) cluster computing framework, then use Hello World from  it's [site](http://spark.apache.org)